# How to detect is my assembly running in WP7/WP8 environment?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm doing a library, which I want to detect if it's running in a WP7/WP8 environment. How to do that using .NET?

EDIT:

I forget to mention I want to detect it at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to differentiate between existing platforms that .NET runs on - take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd282469.aspx) MSDN page about cross-platform conditional compilation symbols.

The currently defined platforms are Windows, XBox and Windows Phone.

Comment: Thanks, but actually I need to do that at runtime.

Comment: :) If you're using a portable class library - you have no choice but to use something like Environment.OSVersion (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx) but if you're recompiling the same sources in different projects (for different targets), you can use the defines I suggested above to conditionally assign a value to a property on a static class that you can check at runtime. Remember, in a Portable Class Library, you are already limited to the intersection of features that all the platforms support - so you can't even compile the alternate path code.

Comment: Environment.OSVersion is unsupported in a PCL

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 8 SDK is not yet released, therefore currently there is no way to find that out.